# How do I disable HTML5 validation in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I'm looking for a setting (`about:config`) that will turn off browser validation of HTML5 input elements like `type="email"` and `max="5"`, etc.

I'm not looking for a plugin, and the `novalidate` attribute is not the answer because I am looking for a browser setting to change *my* browser on *all sites*, not to change a specific site for all browsers.

I've tried searching for "html5" and "validation" in `about:config`, but have not found anything useful.

Comment: Might be relevant, called HTML5 Toggle (not personnaly tested) : http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/enable-or-disable-html5-support-in-firefox-with-html-5-toggle/

Comment: The only keys with `HTML5` in them are `html5.flushtimer.initialdelay`, `html5.flushtimer.subsequentdelay`, and `html5.offmainthread`.